# Prevent CAS authentication if X.509 user isn't registered

Tags: cas

I have [X.509 authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/X509-Authentication.html) set up in [Apereo CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/), and it works fine.  I also got `cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc` settings working so that additional attributes are retrieved from a database table when the user authenticates successfully.

But if there is no matching row in my table, the user is still authenticated.  He's just missing the various attributes from the table's columns.  I want authentication to fail in that case.  How could that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if there is no matching row in my table...I want authentication to fail in that case. How could that be accomplished?

The proper way to do this would be to see if this setting can help you:

```
cas.authn.x509.principal.principalResolutionFailureFatal=true
```

The note for the setting says:

> When true, throws an error back indicating that principal resolution has failed and no principal can be found based on the authentication requirements. Otherwise, simply logs the condition as an error without raising a catastrophic error.

Comment: This was the hint I needed, thank you!  There is a little extra needed to make it work, though.  First, the value has to be in the X.509 settings, not the global `cas.personDirectory` settings, i.e. `cas.authn.x509.principal.principalResolutionFailureFatal=true`.  Also, you must set `cas.authn.x509.principal.returnNull=true`, otherwise the principal resolution still "succeeds."

Comment: That makes sense; I'd forgotten that X509 has its own settings for principal resolution. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See if  `Enforce Attribute` is what you want: https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-Service-Access-Strategy.html#enforce-attributes

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "testId",
  "name" : "testId",
  "id" : 1,
  "accessStrategy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
    "enabled" : true,
    "ssoEnabled" : true,
    "requiredAttributes" : {
      "@class" : "java.util.HashMap",
      "YOUR_JDBC_RETURN_ATTRIBUTE" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "*" ] ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here, * works because  `Enforce Attribute` support regex, see this:

https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/v5.3.9/core/cas-server-core-services-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/services/DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy.java#L298

Comment: This is useful information, +1.  I could have used this technique if the `principalResolutionFailureFatal` setting had not been an option.

Comment: No problem, the proper way was much better :)